# adjust the speed of the playback of a video

Tags: objective-c

is there a way to adjust the speed of the playback of a video while playing in Objective C for the iPhone/iPod touch?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `float currentPlayBackRate`. This should gives you the ability to change the speed. When you assign currentPlayBackRate 0.0 it indicates movie playback stopped. When it equal one it means normal speed.
["Apple: MPMediaPlayback Protocol"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009268)